# Unable to copy an array after using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

```
void replace(char* str) {
    unsigned int len = 0;
    unsigned int no_of_spaces = 0;
    char* temp = str;
    int* space_positions = NULL;
    while (*temp) {
        if ((char)*temp == SPACE) {
            no_of_spaces++;
        }
        temp++;
        len++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", len); / prints correct value

    void* str_copy_allocation = (char*) malloc((sizeof(char) * len) + 1);
    char* str_copy = NULL;
    if (str_copy_allocation)
        str_copy = str_copy_allocation;
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid allocation occured");
        perror("Error printed by perror");
    }
    temp = str; // point to starting of str
    while (*temp != '\0') {
        *str_copy++ = *temp++;
        printf("%c\n", *str_copy);
    }
    str_copy[len] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", str_copy);

    temp = str_copy; // to the start of str_copy
    unsigned int new_len = len + 2 * no_of_spaces + 1;
    str_copy = realloc(temp, new_len);
    if (str_copy == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid reallocation occured");
        perror("Error printed by perror");
    }
    str_copy[new_len] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", str_copy);
}
```

Here I am trying to make a copy of a char array and then increase its size. I am getting `Aborted (core dumped)` when I copy the value of `temp` to `str_copy`. Since `str` is a user-defined string, in order to increase it's size I must make a copy of it. That copy is `str_cpy` and then I will increase size of `str_cpy` and return that as the new string.

The print statement `printf("%c\n", *str_copy);` in the while loop prints empty character!

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems, firstly as user312023 pointed out at the line `str_copy[len] = '\0';` str_copy has been incremented. You need to put `str_copy = str_copy_allocation;`above this line to point back to the start of the string.

The other problem is your printf loop

```
    while (*temp != '\0') {
        *str_copy++ = *temp++;
        printf("%c\n", *str_copy);
    }
```

The str_copy has already been incremented when you print, so you're printing the next character in str_copy (which you havent copied from temp yet). To see what you copied you should increment str_copy after the print, like this

```
    while (*temp != '\0') {
        *str_copy = *temp++;
        printf("%c\n", *str_copy++);
    }
```

With these two changes the code works.

EDIT: Another issue is that when you enlarge the string with the reallocation, and put the null terminator on the end, your string already has a null terminator in it at position `str_copy[len]`, that was copied from the smaller length string. So any functions to act on that string wont consider the extra memory youve allocated, as they will stop at the first null terminator.

To show this, try using the function on some string, eg
`replace("my string");`

Then in the function, at the end before the final printf, add something like `str_copy[len+1]='x';`.

You will notice this x isnt printed, because printf stopped at the first null terminator, which is at the 'end' of the string before you reallocated more memory. If you instead do `str_copy[len]='x'; str_copy[len+1]='x'`, then both x's are printed because youve overwritten the null terminator you copied from the precious string.

So to fix this, simply put `str_copy[len]=' ';` before or after the line that says `str_copy[new_len]='\0';`, and this will overwrite the null terminator from the smaller string.

Comment: But `str_copy[len]` is supposed to the last element of the array. It is being set to `\0` after the previous elements have been added to the array!

Comment: Yes but in the while loop directly above, you increment str_copy, so when you get to this line str_copy is already pointing to the end of the array. You need to reset it to point back to the start of the array before you can do `str_copy[len]`

Comment: You could also do `*str_copy = '\0';` then put `str_copy = str_copy_allocation;` on the line after instead of the line before, which would do the same thing.

Comment: Oh!, I did not know `str_copy = str_copy_allocation;` puts the pointer in the start of the array. The increment of the size is not happenning. Even after the realloc it does not increase the size. `str_copy[new_len + 100] = 's';` did not raise any error!!
Rest of the outputs are fine.

Comment: The increment of the size is happening - the printf isnt showing it though because you copied the null terminator from the smaller string. I edited a better explanation into my answer, does this make sense?